# Load testing of Web UI for 20K users

Tags: javascript, selenium, load-testing, webui

I have developed automation scripts for end to end workflows using selenium webdriver io for my web application. I want to use same scripts for load testing. My requirement is to test web UI along with backend APIs for 20K users. Can you please suggest how I can achieve it with Selenium?

Answer (score 0):

For 20K users you will need 20k browsers, for 20k browsers you will need I don't know how many in reality, but looking into [Firefox 87 system requirements](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/87.0/system-requirements/):

- a [CPU core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-core_processor) per browser instance
- 2 GB of RAM per browser instance

If you have such a supercomputer somewhere or possess a budget to kick off that many machines in cloud - you can [scale your Selenium tests using i.e. K8S cluster](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/How-%20to-Scale-Selenium-Tests-in-a-Kubernetes-Cluster)

However it might be a better idea considering converting your Selenium tests into HTTP-protocol-based load tests, the majority of load testing tools provide [HTTP Proxy server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server) for recording tests so you can [replay your Selenium tests via this proxy](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/http_proxies/) and get them converted into a load testing tool script.

Protocol-based tests have much smaller footprint in terms of CPU and RAM so you should be able to use reasonably small hardware for conducting your tests.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your reply. If I want to test frond end of the application (Web UI) under a load, is there any other tool I can use?

Comment: Use a load testing tool to create the load and use Selenium with 1-2 threads for checking the frontend performance. If you're looking for a specific tool you can consider [Apache JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/), it is possible to quickly [convert Selenium tests to JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-convert-selenium-scripts-jmx-converter) and there is JMeter integration with Selenium via [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) you you can use [Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/) for running both side-by-side